# changed Navigation bar iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar

Apple has recently approved my app which was created for iOS 6.1+. There is a navigation bar in the app style set to black. But once I run the app on the iOS 7, the navigation bar is standard blue. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you deploy using Xcode 5?

Comment: could you post some screenshots?

Comment: @RyanG no I've upgraded my xcode after archiving and uploading app.

Comment: Did you test your app under iOS 7?

Comment: @rmaddy once I run my app in iOS 7 simulator it looks pretty different from real iOS 7 device. The nav bar looks completely different (blank white) as in many other iOS 7 apple apps. So nothing really common with how my app looks on in iOS 7 on real device.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    if ([self.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {

        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor    = [UIColor blackColor];

    }
```